# What's a term for words that occur in different parts of speech?

Tags: roots

For example:

Strategy, (n); Strategic, (adj); Strategise, (v); Strategically, (adv); or

Context, Contextual, Contextualise; or

Analysis, Analytical, Analyse.

These words, that occur as different parts of speech are called __________??

(It's like head words, roots, lemmas, families etc., but none of these seems to fit exactly).

Thanks, K

Answer (score 1):

It comes under morphology. It is derivation.

Comment: Precisely. English doesn't have much [inflectional morphology](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/inflection.pdf) left; virtually every process (prefix, suffix, root change, zero affix) that changes POS is derivational.